# Background task with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, capistrano, sbt, nohup

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I cannot manage to get it right. I have already looked at :

- [Starting background tasks with Capistrano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109274/starting-background-tasks-with-capistrano)
- [launching background process in capistrano task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889621/launching-background-process-in-capistrano-task)
- http://whowish-programming.blogspot.fr/2011/04/run-background-process-with-capistrano.html

I am using capistrano to deploy a server in scala. My task looks like this :

```
desc "Start server"
task :start do
    run "cd #{deploy_to} && ./sbt compile start-script"
    run "cd #{deploy_to} && export PORT=#{server_port} && export ENV=#{env} && nohup target/start > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
end
```

[start-script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) is an sbt plugin that creates a script in target/start.
When I run the task, the output is :

```
  * executing "cd /home/ubuntu/* && export PORT=* && export ENV=integration && nohup target/start > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
    servers: ["54.217.224.197"]
    [54.217.224.197] executing command
    command finished in 1015ms
```

but my server is not started... When omitting the "&" at the end of the command, the server is started but the capistrano script is blocked.

```
  * executing "cd /home/ubuntu/* && export PORT=* && export ENV=integration && nohup target/start > /dev/null 2>&1"
    servers: ["54.217.224.197"]
    [54.217.224.197] executing command
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, just add pty: false at the end

```
run "cd #{deploy_to} && export PORT=#{server_port} && export ENV=#{env} && nohup target/start > /dev/null 2>&1 &" pty: false
```