# Running a capistrano task in background

Tags: deployment, rake, backgroundworker, daemon, capistrano3

I have a cap task that call multiple other long running cap tasks:

So lets say I have a task named `A`

From within this cap task I (depending on condition) call another cap task lets say `B`.

cap task `B` sequentially calls 4 more cap tasks `c`, `D`, `E`, & ,`F`

So be is something like this:

```
task :B do
    on roles(:all) do
        invoke 'tasks:C'
        invoke 'tasks:D'
        Rake::Task['db:E'].invoke("arg1", "arg2")
        Rake::Task['db:F'].invoke("arg1", "arg2")
    end
end
```

Each of C, D, E & F are long running and must run sequentially in same order as specified.

Basically tasks C to F are db & assets zipping and uploading tasks which might take long time, so they must not hinder the cap deployment process and should run independently in background.

So I need a way to call task `B` from task `A` so that it runs in async mode, and rest of cap tasks during deployment keep running.

Comment: To clarify: Are tasks C-F supposed to finish before the completion of the Capistrano run, or are they long running background processes/daemons?

Comment: Long running background process [I will update my question]

Comment: So C-F will eventually finish, but a deployment can be considered done before they do?

Comment: Yes, before deployment, I stop the servers, initiate db and asset backups and upload in background, and complete deployment and restart server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest making task B an actual Rake task, and then having Capistrano call and immediately background it, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829142/3042016

Comment: Thanks, I made a ruby script for all four tasks combined to one, uploaded it to the server and then ran it in the background using `nohup`. Worked like a charm